# Ring of hircine and saviors hide

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible to obtain both the saviors hide AND the ring hircine? I believe I heard it was possible and if it is can someone tell me how I can do this

Comment: In case you're wondering about the downvote or lack of upvotes, I'm not upvoting due to lack of research, which is probably what the downvote is for. Googling "Ring of Hircine Savior's hide" gives you several results that explain this.

Comment: @DCShannon I can't google anything on wiki or any other gaming forums because I use a school iPad which things like wiki, and gaming sites are blocked. I don't have resources. I'm 13 and I don't have a phone. My options are pretty limited

Comment: Since we ask you to show what research you've done, indicating that you can't do any would probably help. Here's an upvote, now that you've explained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually get both the Ring of Hircine, and the Saviour's Hide in one save, due to this quest being bugged.

It is possible to obtain both of these rewards using one of a number of similar exploits:

- **PC/360/PS3** Kill all the hunters, speak to Sinding, go outside the grotto and claim the Ring of Hircine, then go back in and kill Sinding to get his skin. The spirit will reappear from Sinding's corpse and offer the Savior's Hide.
- **PC/360/PS3** If the above doesn't work, kill and skin Sinding immediately after killing the hunters and talking to him. As soon as the Hircine spirit appears, back out of the conversation and run out of the grotto where the White Stag spirit will appear and bless the ring to break the curse. Return to the grotto and resume conversation with the Hircine spirit to receive the Savior's Hide.
- **PC** A further way that can work to receive both rewards (if the first method results in not being able to skin Sinding upon return and the second method results in a non-speaking Aspect of Hircine in the grotto upon return) is to kill the hunters, kill Sinding near the exit, complete the conversation quickly to claim the Savior's Hide and then sprint to the exit to claim the Ring outside.
- **PC/PS3/360** Leave the grotto along with Sinding after killing the hunters. When the Stag spirit appears, back out of the conversation and kill Sinding, then skin him and speak with the spirit emerging from his corpse for the Savior's Hide. Speak to the Stag spirit again for the ring.
- **PS3** A fourth way to obtain both the ring and the hide, if you originally obtained the ring, is to return to the grotto at any time in the game. Upon entering the main area you will see Sinding in werewolf form. Killing this version of Sinding will only result in obtaining ragged trousers. However, if you follow the trail through the grotto, as you did on the original hunt, you will find yourself on a ledge overlooking the main entrance area with a second version of Sinding--one on the ledge with you, and another below. If you kill the second version of Sinding you receive the option to skin him, causing the aspect of Hircine to appear and convert the skin into the Savior's Hide.
- **PS3/360** After completing the quest to obtain the Ring of Hircine (killing the Hunters and sparing Sinding) you can sometimes find Sinding back in the jail cell in werewolf form. I RECOMMEND SAVING BEFORE CONTINUING AT THIS POINT. With some careful positioning and good timing, and a hell of a lot of good luck, you can kill Sinding the cell, and then upon inspecting the corpse, the option to skin him will become available, and then the Spirit of Hircine will appear in the from of Sinding, and offer you the Hide.

Answer (score 2):

You can, (I stand corrected).

To get both the ring and hide, help Sinding kill the hunters, leave the grotto to receive the ring, then go back inside the grotto, kill and skin Sinding and receive the Savior's Hide.

Comment: You can also use the console to add them to your inventory using the following commands:
player.additem 0002AC60 1
player.additem 0002AC61 1